# Pattern Recognition Puzzle

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

I would like some help explaining the pattern on this puzzle. It is from a game on my phone and I can only use a number pad to answer. There are no negative signs.

Puzzle:

```
8    13 
16   6
4    19
22   2
?    32
```

I noticed it decreases by two and increases by three in a zigzag manner but I do not see how it helps me determine the "?".

Through guessing I found the number to be 7, but I cannot explain it. Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which game is this?  Any context here might be helpful.

Comment: It is called Math Puzzles from the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are 5,10,15,20,25 with the smaller number on the left, right, left, right, left.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $42$ of course, and the function is:

$$f(x)=\frac{839x^4}{7814016}-\frac{2075x^3}{279072}+\frac{55855x^2}{279072}-\frac{91127x}{28728}+\frac{84112}{2907}$$

Comment: odd response to a simple pattern puzzle..  you may have answered the wrong question

Comment: @serey: No I haven't. Please feel free to check my answer and verify that $f(8)=13$, $f(16)=6$, $f(4)=19$, $f(22)=2$, and of course, $f(42)=32$. No mistake here.

Comment: @serey: Though in order to understand the actual point of my answer, you need to read between the lines. Can you spot it?

Comment: oh! thank you for the clarification! sorry, due to the game being relatively childish I doubted your function and it's large numbers... you are not incorrect haha, but online games are not as accepting with their answers

Comment: This answer is valid for almost everything from life to the universe.

Comment: There are infinitely many answers equally true as this one. It's a worse answer than "The answer is 1 because these numbers are the sequence $(8,13,16,6,4,19,22,2,1,32)$".

Answer (score 0):

i know the game :)
42 not working ;)

7 is right..
8  + 1*5 = 13 (first row)
16 - 2*5 = 6  (second row)
4  + 3*5 = 19 (3rd row)
22 - 4*5 = 2  (4th ...)
7  + 5*5 = 32 (5th row... and so on, +/- x*5)